# What happened to the art style in Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail

What happened to the art style in Fairy Tail after episode 175?

**Old art style:**

[image: Old art style]

**New art style:**

[image: New art style]

Answer (score 17):

After episode 175 **the production studio changed** from [A-1 Pictures](http://a1p.jp/) & [Satelight](http://www.satelight.co.jp/) to [A-1 Pictures](http://a1p.jp/) & [Bridge](http://www.bridge-inc.co.jp/).

**Character designer change,** before episode 175 character design was done by 'Aoi Yamamoto' after that by 'Shinji Takeuchi' and 'Toshihiko Sano'.

**Art director change,** before episode 175 character design was done by 'Junko Shimizu' after that by 'Shigeru Morimoto'.

If you are interested in the rest of the staff check out [this](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=10942) page for everything before episode 175, and [this](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15799) page for everything after 175.

*The new animation places emphasis on the special attacks, fast-paced scenes, overall story's color, clarity, and fluidity. Some people will like the change some don't. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCIo039VRfo) is a video that shows some differences with character design.*